# How can I filter incoming packets to my application?

Tags: wireshark, packet, traffic-filtering

I have only little experience with Wireshark. The problem is that when my server (3rd party app) receives a faulty packets, it crashes. I would need to filter the incoming packets and filter out such a message before it reaches the server application.
Can I do that in the Wireshark and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is DPI filtering/tampering proxy/firewall/netfilter, here's some of them:

- http://www.costcentral.com/proddetail/Trend_Micro_Deep_Security_Deep_Packet_Inspection_Firewall/DXRF0029/11050777/    ($243.30, duh)
- http://packet.ab-archive.net/filtering.html
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content-control_software

But the tool you most probably would apply sucsessfully is **Ettercap**:

- http://ettercap.github.io/ettercap/index.html

Do you use Windows?

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/ettercap/files/unofficial%20binaries/windows/

You can drop or fix (if feasible) faulty packets:

> Packet filtering/dropping: setting up a filter that searches for a particular string (or hexadecimal sequence) in the TCP or UDP payload and replaces it with a custom string/sequence of choice, or drops the entire packet.

Comment: Thanks, I found that simple WPE Pro can do that perfectly ;)

Comment: Nice find! [padding]